# S3 presigned URL only accessible when generated from local backend

Tags: node.js, react-native, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a react native app that shows images by accessing their S3 presigned URLs through `<Image source='...'>`.

I'm not sure if this is how presigned URLs are supposed to work but currently:

1. When the front-end renders a list of items, it requests these items from the backend.
2. For each item, the backend generates a presigned URL using the following code:

```js
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
  region: 'us-east-2'
});

function getSignedUrl(key) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {
      Bucket: 'bucket-name',
      Key: key,
      Expires: 7200,
    };

    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, (err, url) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(url);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

3. The front-end uses each presigned URL returned from the request as the corresponding image source.

The EC2 instance is associated to an IAM role that has the policy `AmazonS3FullAccess`.

The S3 bucket has the "Block all public access" off and the following bucket policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

### The problem

When I test this with the local backend the front-end shows the images as expected. But when I test it with the backend hosted in EC2 it does not work.

If I try to access the images through their regular URLs it does work so I guess the problem is related to the presigned URLs access.